# python3.4 under Windows7 encoding issuу - \u2014

Tags: encoding, python-3.4

I have 'em dash' character in my python code to split by it a line in a certain txt file.

```
with open(path, 'r') as r:
    number = r.readline()
    num = number.split(' — ')[1].replace('\n',' — ')
```

It worked fine under ubuntu with python3.4, but when running the code under windows 7 (python3.4) get the following error.

> num = number.split(' \u2014 ')[1].replace('\n',' \u2014 ') IndexError:
>   list index out of range

I'm sure that it should work and It seems that the problem is in encoding.
Will appreciate any help to fix my programm. I've tried to set "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" without any result

---

SOLUTION WAS `open(path, mode, encoding='UTF8')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do:

```
num = number.split(' — ')[1].replace('\n',' — ')
```

you assume that the string 'number' contains a dash, and then take the second field ([1]), if number does not contains a dash then [1] does not exists, only [0] exists, and you get the index out of range response.

```
if ' — ' in number: 
   num = number.split(' — ')[1].replace('\n',' — ')
else:
   num = number.replace('\n',' — ')
```

furthermore, as you are now on Windows, you might want to check for '\r\n' as well as '\n' depending what the file is using as end of line character(s)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree that it looks like an absent of 'em dash' but I know for sure that it is there. Exactly the same code and file under linux goes without any error.

Comment: @Oromay If you like my answer, and it works for you; flag my answer as answer :-) ... and/or vote up ! :-) ... you're welcome, I am sure there are shorter answers then an if/else statement... if I find one, I will edit.

Comment: I think that under windows python interpret the sign (' — ') in code differently and that's why it can't find it in the file.

Comment: if you know the encoding, you can add something like `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top (very first line of your .py script) and then use the `\u2014` in your `.split()`

Comment: Thank you for the help. The solution which worked for me was using ecnoding while openning file 'open(path, mode, encoding='UTF8')'